# Comparing the two images using OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n33ky.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEjf1.png)

Above I have 2 images. As you can see, they are very similar. The only difference is the color. Is there anyway that I can compare the image, and show the differences as the final result?

I had already try different methods - Template Matching, Feature Matching, Contours, waterShed Algorithm, Masking, compare_ssim, etc. But none of them are actually working according to my plan. Thank you. I am grateful for your help.

P.S. Here is one result that I get for Feature Matching (I used Flann Base Matcher Algorithm) [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkEEy.png)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are searching for the [`RANSAC`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html) algorithm:

RANSAC is an old, robust feature-matching algorithm, used to find the similarity between given images.

For instance in your case, if we apply RANSAC:

[image]

Code: (originally adapted from this [link](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html))

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10
img1 = cv.imread('image1.png', 0)  # queryImage
img2 = cv.imread('image2.png', 0)  # trainImage
# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
# find the key points and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2, None)
index_params = dict(algorithm=1, trees=5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)
flann = cv.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)
# store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
good = []
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
        good.append(m)
    if len(good) > MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
        src_pts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
        dst_pts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
        M, mask = cv.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv.RANSAC, 5.0)
        matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()
        h, w = img1.shape
        pts = np.float32([[0, 0], [0, h - 1], [w - 1, h - 1], [w - 1, 0]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
        dst = cv.perspectiveTransform(pts, M)
        img2 = cv.polylines(img2, [np.int32(dst)], True, 255, 3, cv.LINE_AA)

draw_params = dict(matchColor=(0, 255, 0),  # draw matches in green color
                   singlePointColor=None,
                   matchesMask=matchesMask,  # draw only in-liers
                   flags=2)
img3 = cv.drawMatches(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, good, None, **draw_params)
plt.imshow(img3, 'gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```